# Best highperf database for simple read/write (no update) scenario

Tags: database, performance, nosql, scalability

I'm interested in opinions on what database system to select for this project where I basically need to persist a constant stream of messages at potentially high speed. There's basically four types of messages with some commonalities. No relations needed. I guess you could call it an *event store*.

I will need to *read* (query by a non-unique key), but I don't need to update any data. I will have to delete old data though.

Considerations:

- Database must be able to scale out
- Performance is crucial
- as well as up-time (system allowing live updates would be nice)
- Preferably something running on Windows Server, but this is not a requirement

I'm familiar with document databases (MongoDB), but don't know what other kinds of NoSQL solutions would fit my problem, or how they compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb would be ideal. But if all you want to do is read from the stream and serve up content, more than database consideration (use any db - mysql, access, sql server express, xml files), I would suggest you look at putting all your data in memory (maybe at app startup); and then serve up data from memory.

You should also look at some caching solutions like Memcached (http://memcached.org/)

Comment: I've done some performance tests on MongoDB, and it's more than fast enough for my need. I was hoping for some more detailed answers, but since there are none, I'll award you the correct answer ;)